# New command with default does not work

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

Hello I have the following new command (a bit simplified for readability):

```
\newcommand{\xz}[1][0]{x_{#1}}
```

I'm expecting the following behavior:

```
$\xz$ outputs as $x_0$
$\xz{1}$ outputs as $x_1$
```

Though, the compiled result returns:

```
$\xz$ outputs as $x_0$ (ok!)
$\xz{1}$ outputs as $x_01$ (??)
```

What I'm missing there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You declared an optional argument, so you need to use `\xz[1]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xz}[1][0]{x_{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\xz\quad\xz[1]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\xz{1}` will be understood as `\xz` without the optional argument and then `{1}`.

Comment: I would accept immediately, but I can accept the answer in 10 minutes. It's obviously true. And I have to sleep!! Thanks :)